# How to make CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent and CGEventPost combo equivalent to CGPostKeyboardEvent?

Tags: objective-c, macos, quartz-graphics

I'm trying to send keystrokes for systemwide keyboard shortcut (Like control-F4) using `CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent` and `CGEventPost` but not succeeding.  Sending such keystrokes using `CGPostKeyboardEvent` worked just fine but the method became deprecated and I'm looking for an alternative.

```
CGPostKeyboardEvent((CGCharCode)0, (CGKeyCode)118/*F4*/, true); // worked

CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, (CGKeyCode)118/*F4*/, true)); // doesn't work
```

Would someone tell me what is wrong or something I should read into?  I'm afraid that this ability of `CGPostKeyboardEvent` to issue systemwide shortcut is a reason of deprecation.  Any input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I got an answer via stackoverflow Japan http://goo.gl/nACVPz and confirmed that the following code works!

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState);

        CGEventRef f4 = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, kVK_F4, true);
        CGEventSetFlags(f4, kCGEventFlagMaskControl);
        CGEventTapLocation location = kCGHIDEventTap;

        CGEventPost(location, f4);

        CFRelease(f4);
        CFRelease(source);
    }
    return 0;
}
```